# How to build node.js projects against local versions of the dependencies?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I've been trying to build a relatively complex node.js project (https://github.com/edrlab/thorium-reader/) against local versions of some dependencies.

I can build and run the project with the non-local dependencies without problems.

I've tried different "routes", such as adding the dependencies using `npm install --save <path-to-dependency>` or just adding a `file:<path-to-dependency>` reference to the `package.json` file. I've checked out the exact versions of each dependency.

`npm install` doesn't show any errors.

Now when I run `npm run start` I get type errors that don't quite understand, such as:

```
Argument of type 'import("~/repositories/thirdparty/thorium/r2-opds-js/dist/es6-es2015/src/opds/opds2/opds2-facet").OPDSFacet' 
is not assignable to parameter of type 
'import("~/repositories/thirdparty/thorium/thorium-reader/node_modules/r2-opds-js/dist/es6-es2015/src/opds/opds2/opds2-facet").OPDSFacet'.
      Types of property 'Links' are incompatible.
```

Does anyone have a hint for me what I am doing wrong here ?

I'm using node.js version 17.2.0 and npm version 8.2.0.

Best,
N

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after fiddling around for hours I found that using `npm link` does the trick. Not sure what the differences are, `npm install` didn't work at all, neither did putting the references in `package.json`.

That is, go to the dependency's repository, run `npm link`, build the dependency as a module, THEN go to the main repository and run `npm link <dependency> --save`.

Now the build process works.

Not sure why there are the two different method, one of which doesn't work a all in this case.